# Windows Services does not show up in the service list

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services, setup-project, .net-1.1

I have to create a service in .NET 1.1 and to install that service using the setup project. I successfully installed the service but it didn't show up in the service list.

Comment: if you use installutil.exe, the problem is the same? With installutil you can see errors if the install is not successful.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070885/specify-windows-service-name-on-install-with-setup-project and many others. I found them by searching for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22windows+service%22+install

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem once and I asked this question: [C#: Running and Debugging a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711241/c-running-and-debugging-a-windows-service)

The problem was that I didn't add an `Service Installer` to the Service.  Try adding a `Service Installer` to your service and your service should appear in the `services.msc` list.